# sniffing IE8 only

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, detection

What's the shortest javascript code to sniff if the browser is IE8.

I want to do something special just for IE8

I don't want to wire up a library that gives me back all the browsers and the versions.
I just want to write one or two lines to work out if it's IE8.

thanks
zo

Comment: [Google- how to detect ie8 in javascript](http://goo.gl/LbsXR).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this in HTML, by using this:

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="IE8.js">
<![endif]-->
```

Also take a look at this tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537509%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: That will check for IE8 or greater. To check for IE8 only use <!--[if IE 8]>

Answer (score 10):

The best way I found is to use conditional styles, or conditional compiling:

```
var isIE8 = false;
<!--[if IE 8]>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            isIE8 = true;
        </script>
<![endif]-->
```

Then in your code, you can simply check this value:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
   if (isIE8) {
       alert('Your browser is IE8');
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your HTML, you can include markup for certain IE browsers using conditional comments:

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ie8_hacks.js">
<![endif]-->
```